# Can’t attach image to a task

Tags: javascript, image, api, file, asana

As the title says, I’m trying to attach a file to an existing task, I’m using Nodejs and request() for doing so, but the response says: 400 Bad Request.

I’m going to show you the code for you to see if i’m doing something wrong.

```js
let contents = imagen.image, //this is an array buffer with the image
    imageData64 = imagen.imageData64, //this is a base64 code with the mimetype
    returnedB64 = imagen.returnedB64,// this is just the base64 code
    blob = Buffer.from(returnedB64, ‘base64’),
    formData = new FormData();

formData.append("file", contents);

const options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: asanaUrl,
    headers: {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        "boundary": "1z2x3c4v5b",
        "Authorization": "Basic  my token",
    },
    formData: {
        "image": formData,
        "file": contents
    }
};

IMPORTS.request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    console.log(res.statusMessage);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

I’ll thank you so much if you could help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the Asana endpoint you're hitting and what is the response from their api? Have you looked at the docs? `400` means bad request, so there might be a param/header/etc. missing.

Comment: Yes, I know what that means, I changed the paameters to this,

Comment: "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + element.file_name + "\"",
 "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=1z2x3c4v5b",
                                                "Authorization": "Bearer token",
                                            },
                                            formData: {
                                                task_gid: taskId,
                                                file: blob file

but, it is not working

Comment: this is the url I'm sending the request to    

let taskId = result.data.id,
asanaUrl = 'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/' + taskId + '/attachments';

Comment: Which library are you using for the request to the api?

Comment: This is the library I'm using to send requests to asana: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request